# Parsing JSON from OpenWeatherMap in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, httprequest, openweathermap

I've got the connection to work, but **I cant manage to get the description from weather Array. Because it is a Dictionary inside an Array**.

```
{"weather":
[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}]}
```

Getting the temperature works fine like this:

```
if let main = item["main"] as? NSDictionary {
            println("Main existe")
            if let temp = main["temp"] {
                println("Temp existe")
                weatherRequested.append(temp.stringValue)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up working out a solution:

```
 if let item = jsonResult as? NSDictionary {

        if let weather = item["weather"] as? NSArray{
            if let value = weather[0] as? NSDictionary{
                if let description = value["description"] as? String{
                    weatherRequested.append(description)
                }
            }
        }
        if let main = item["main"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let temp = main["temp"] {
                weatherRequested.append(temp.stringValue)
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for anyone who tried to help me anyways! :)

Comment: You're casting `value["description"] as? NSMutableString` and then again casting it `as String`. It makes no sense, you should directly cast it as String.

Comment: It didnt let me cast directly from NSDictionary to String, had to go through NSMutableString first. It is working fine like that.

Comment: You should cast `value["description"]` directly `as? String`, not `as? NSMutableString`. Then you won't have to cast again in the `append`.

Comment: I read it wrong, my bad. It works fine the way I wrote it, but what you are saying makes a lot of sense. I'll make that change!

Comment: Good. Now your answer is much better. :)

Answer (score 3):

The default JSON parsing in iOS with Swift is plain bad. I would suggest you to use `SwiftyJSON` library. That would make parsing it as easy as...

```
let result = JSON(jsonResult)
let weatherDesc = result["weather"]["description"].stringValue
let weatherTemp = result["main"]["temp"].stringValue
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've read that apple turns down apps because the use of third party libraries that they dont like, so I was trying to avoid using such libraries and sticking to apples stuff even if its a little more complex/painfull

Comment: @PabloDuque: nope i've got an accepted app on the App store that uses this library and many others!

Comment: Oh great!!! sorry for the dumb question, but how do I properly import such a library? :S Thanks

Comment: Use a dependency manager like Cocoapods. Then it is as simple as adding `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'` to your Podfile and running `pod install`. Check https://cocoapods.org

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in

```
if let item = jsonResult[0] as? NSDictionary {
```

jsonResult is an NSDictionary not an Array. Delete "[0]" and try again